# Accessing values of ActionController Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need to access to the `attachments` values, I can't find the way 
it says permitted false, it's allowed in the strong parameters though...

```
 <ActionController::Parameters {
        "utf8"=>"✓", 
        "authenticity_token"=>"wMY3FheLXzezCBO8phfst85DGdSBmVRl+nljAUYviYxZsWXMXC+Rcddit3XaNNikaGTvdLH+rx5ZNh6bY31Yzw==", 
        "finished_guitar"=><ActionController::Parameters 
            { "title"=>"my super title",
             "description"=>"and my awsome description"
             } permitted: false>,
        "commit"=>"Create Finished guitar",
        "params"=>{
            "attachments"=>[{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcfa084fa90 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20180902-64552-9bms50.jpg>,
            @original_filename="image_1.jpg",
            @content_type="image/jpeg", 
            @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"params[attachments][][image]\"; 
            filename=\"image_1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">
        }]
         },"controller"=>"finished_guitars", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

my controller:

```
class FinishedGuitarsController < ApplicationController

  def index
      @finished_guitars = FinishedGuitar.all
  end

  def show
      @finished_guitar = FinishedGuitar.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @finished_guitar = FinishedGuitar.new
    @attachments = @finished_guitar.attachments.build
  end

  def create
    @finished_guitar = FinishedGuitar.new(finished_guitar_params)
        if @finished_guitar.save
          unless params[:attachments].nil?
            params[:attachments]['image'].each do |a|
                @finished_guitar = @finished_guitar.attachments.create!(:image => a, :finished_guitar_id => @finished_guitar.id)
            end
          end
          render json: { finishedGuitardId: @finished_guitar.id, attachments: @finished_guitar.attachments_attributes }, status: 200
        else
            render json: { error: @finished_guitar.errors.full_messages.join(", ") }, status: 400 
        end
  end

  private
    def finished_guitar_params
        params.require(:finished_guitar).permit(:title, :description, attachments_attributes: [:id, :image, :finished_guitar_id])
    end
end
```

### UPDATE

I am just adding the `_form.html.erb`

```
<div class="content">
    <%= simple_form_for @finished_guitar, html: {multipart: true, id: "my-dropzone", class: "dropzone" } do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :title %>
        <%= f.input :description %>

        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
            <h3>Drop file here</h3> or
            <strong>click</strong> to upload
        </div>
        <div class="fallback">      
            <br><br>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :attachments do |ff| %>
            <%= ff.input_field :image, as: :file, multiple: true, name: "finished_guitar[attachments_attributes][][image]" %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
                    <br><br>

        <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>     
</div>
```

I can upload my files if I remove `"my-dropzone", class: "dropzone"`from `<%= simple_form_for @finished_guitar, html: {multipart: true, id: "my-dropzone", class: "dropzone" } do |f| %>`

Comment: Try `params[:finished_guitar][:attachments]`

Comment: that returns `nil`

Comment: how are you passing the attachments attributes? you've whitelisted `attachments_attributes[]`, but from the strong parameters, only `title` and `description` are included.

Comment: like this: `      params.require(:finished_guitar).permit(:id, :title, :description, attachments_attributes: [:id, :image, :finished_guitar_id])`the thing is that I am using dropzone.js-rails (uploads work when I disable dropzone)

Answer (score 0):

It says `name=params[attachments][][image]`, it seams you have something like:

```
params[:params][:attachments]
```

I'd recommend you to use rails-pry or byebug, stop the execution inside the action and you can easilly inspect the params hash and do thing like `params.keys` or `params[:params]` to see what's actually there

Comment: When I enter `params[:params]["attachments"]`in my break point I receive:
`<ActionController::Parameters {"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc7b90539c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/11/mdddnw8d0zd961bsfkq1cjy00000gn/T/RackMultipart20180902-81768-i66vgw.jpg>, @original_filename="image_2.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"params[attachments][][image]\"; filename=\"image_2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">} permitted: false>`
I need to save the image(s)....

Comment: Since you have `attachments_attributes` on your parameters I suppose you are trying to use nested forms, I guess your form is not coded the right way to use this feature, fix that and you won't need to save the images after `@finished_guitar.save`. Are you using something like cocoon? maybe you did something wrong when configuring it.

Comment: I am not using cocoon, I am using simple form.
I can upload and save my attachments to the finished_guitars when I am not using the **dropzonejs-rails**... everything fail since I use that dropzone gem... 
I rather prefer to have a drag and drop zone than a select files button

Comment: Updated my question with the form

Comment: Hahaha why didn't you said that before? that's really diferent now, I guess dropzone has some config to replicate the fields like nested_attributes_for expect them, I've never used that so I can't help there. Anyway, `params[:params][:attachments][:image]` should by a file parameter, you should be able to call `permit!` on it and assign the images to your model, but would go with properly configuring dropzone